# Webpage will leave navigation bar static but gets rid of Width because of Scroll Bar

Tags: html, css, navigation, scrollbar

The page i am having a problem with is this one: http://www.bkd.com/wealth-advisors/directory-test.htm. The navigation bar is what i want to stay in place which it does now but i want it to keep the 1800px width without adding a horizontal scroll bar. You can see my other pages do that now but don't need a scroll bar (http://www.bkd.com/wealth-advisors/locations-test.htm).

Here is my CSS for the navigation section:

```
#header3dir {
    padding:0px 0px;
    text-align:left;
    height:52px;
}
#header3-contentsdir {
    margin: auto;
    width:1800px;
    padding: 40px 0px;
    background: url(/.../navigation-bar.png) bottom no-repeat;
    height:52px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

If i change the position to fixed it keeps my width and gets rid of the scroll bar but then the navigation scrolls with the page which i do not want. I can change the width of the bar but then on bigger monitors the navigation bar cuts off while the other pages navigation bar continues on.

HTML
'
'

Please let me know if you need any more information. I am here to learn what I need to do so I can fix this problem.

Comment: I see a scrollbar on both sample pages. This seems like it would be a very bad user experience--not being able to access the entire primary navigation mechanism.

Comment: Really @isherwood? What is your screen resolution? I have it programmed for 1280 x 1024. That is a bad user experience. I want the website to work on most screen resolutions which i know is kind of virtually impossible. Also what browser and version are you using?

Comment: I get a scrollbar at about 1280 and the nav items start to become obscured at around 1150. It's not virtually impossible. Google 'responsive web design'.

Comment: Great to know. @isherwood Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me what the problem is or what you want. You should be able to work out a simple, responsive navbar by looking at examples.

Comment: Thank you @isherwood for your help. I have tired responsive navbars before but they never seem to work properly or the way i need it to that's why I built it from scratch. Im really just trying to figure out how to get rid of the horizontal scroll bar on that page but still have my navbar the same width as the others pages that don't add the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Tell you what... create a demo of your navbar at http://jsfiddle.net, then reply here with the link and I'll take a look. Responsive should be fun. :-)

Comment: @isherwood this is what i came up with so far: http://jsfiddle.net/zmL9b/10/embedded/result/   I am needing to know if this will fill the whole screen though without cutting off at the ends.

Comment: Here's a peek at how I'd do it. If your monitor is large enough you'll see 3 distinct layouts as you resize the fiddle frame. See the media queries at the bottom of the CSS frame for how it's done. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/zmL9b/12

Comment: Hey @isherwood got the navigation on my site but it seems some pages are having a problem with it. Like this one: http://www.bkd.com/wealth-advisors/thoughtware-test.htm The navigation is moving all to the left. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks about the same to me on several pages. You'll need to tweak spacing, etc. as needed. Keep learning!

Comment: Thank you @isherwood, any suggestions on how to make it look good in all browsers/resolutions? I seem to be having some issues with smaller resolutions. Thank you again for all your help!

Comment: You don't seem to be using media queries to adjust font sizes and padding like my demo does. If you do that it should stay on one line and render consistently. I'm afraid I can't give much more than that bit of advice.

Comment: I have these in my CSS coding. I played with some of the padding, etc.  a little bit but they are there: media only screen and (max-width: 1900px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    .horizontal-nav ul li a {
        background-position: 0px 5px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .horizontal-nav ul li {
        display: block;
    }
    .horizontal-nav ul li a {
        background-position: 0px 5px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

Comment: Yes, you still have a very large font for your smaller widths. Obviously the menu doesn't fit on one line if you do that.

Comment: Thank you @isherwood for all your help. I got everything working but now in IE8 it looks like if i have the javascript for my navigation and javascript for the pop ups one or the other doesn't work. Any ideas? Navigation not working because of pop ups: http://www.bkd.com/wealth-advisors/directory-test.htm Pops ups not working because of navigation: http://www.bkd.com/wealth-advisors/locations-test.htm